# Why does gem installation ignore PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pkg-config

I'm trying to install a `libxml-ruby` gem which builds native extensions. I've got `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set to the right location for libxml2 and get `pkg-config` can see it:

```
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep -i xml
libxml-2.0                          libXML - libXML library version2.
```

Unfortunately, gem building process does not:

```
$ gem install libxml-ruby
...
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
...
extconf failure: need libxml2.
```

The path list doesn't contain the expected location though:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.8/include/libxml2
```

Why does `pkg-config` settings get ignored here / how to make gem build respect it?

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: @anothermh via `rbenv`

Comment: Have you run [`xcode-select --install`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/6186)?

Comment: @anothermh That's already done. The issue seems to be different than the linked one, since my `pkg-config` is printing a correct / existing include path.

Comment: FWIW, `pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0` returns only `-I/usr/include/libxml2` for me, and from what the linked issue indicates that's provisioned by `xcode-select --install`. Might be worth re-running it to see if anything changes, and also try `brew install libxml-2.0.pc` (or `uninstall` then `install` if you already have it).

Comment: libxml2 is installed and added to PKG_CONFIG_PATH on purpose. I do expect to use the brew one.

Comment: Again, I recommend uninstalling and reinstalling both the Xcode command line tools and the brew package, since from your description they aren't working as you expect them to.

Comment: It's been done, without any effect.

Comment: What if you undo your setting for `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`? I do not have that set and am able to install the gem normally. (macOS 10.14, `libxml-2.0.pc` is not installed)

Comment: @anothermh If I unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH, I get pkg-config result pointing to `/usr/include/libxml2` which doesn't exist. This is not what I want to achieve though - I want to use the specific installation I'm pointing pkg-config at.

Comment: What version of macOS? Do you have the full version of Xcode installed? What is `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set to and how are you setting it? Are you positive that `gem install` has it in the environment? `/usr/include/libxml2` _should exist and have the files_ if you have the Xcode tools installed properly (at least on macOS 10.13 or 10.14), and the fact that it doesn't indicates to me there are other problems here. I get that you want to use the brew version, but I recommend getting it to work the normal-everyday-way first, then see about compiling against the brew version.

Comment: 10.14.1. Full Xcode. Just exporting it. Yes (pkg-config can see it, so gem has to as well). It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If we look how implemented [extconf.rb](https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby/blob/master/ext/libxml/extconf.rb) for **libxml-ruby**, it fails to find headers in predefined locations in **find_header()**. However:

> ```
> Install the library or try one of the following options to extconf.rb:
>
>   --with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config
>   --with-xml2-dir=/path/to/libxml2
>   --with-xml2-lib=/path/to/libxml2/lib
>   --with-xml2-include=/path/to/libxml2/include
> ```

Try:

```
gem install libxml-ruby -- --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.8 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.8/lib --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.8/include/libxml2
```

So, for package installation - makefile is built by gem's extconf.rb. It may use either **pkg-config** or **dir_config** or both; in case of this gem - it's dir_config, which is setup with command line options.